# Getting command history of all opened terminals in one place

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix

I had been working with multiple terminal opened . For some reason my PC rebooted and after when I executed the 'history' command , I could only see the list of commands related to a particular terminal.

Is there any way of getting all histories of all opened terminals .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the other histories back. All your terminals wrote to your history file, and it sounds like you either had too small of a `HISTFILESIZE` value set or you don't have `shopt -s histappend` set to append to the `HISTFILE` instead of overwriting it. In either case, each terminal wrote to the `HISTFILE` in sequence and the list of commands you have left is from the final terminal to do so.

If you want to avoid this in the future, you can set (in your `.bashrc`)

```
shopt -s histappend #append to history file instead of overwriting
HISTFILESIZE=10000 #increase number of stored commands in HISTFILE
```

This will save all your commands grouped by terminal session when you restart. If you'd rather them be time-ordered, you can use this as well:

```
#logs every command as it is written to the history file, 
#and updates local terminal history to match
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```